# fglrx doesn't run on old ubuntu

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ubuntu-10.10

I currently have the version of ubuntu 10.10 (x86) and I don't want to change it. I compiled and installed the linux kernel (3.10.25) and gnu compilers (4.8) without problems.
Because fglrx was not compatible with this version of linux kernel, I had to download the driver from here:

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86

I removed the fglrx package and I run the program to install the new fglrx:
    sudo apt-get remove fglrx
    chmod +x amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run 
    sudo ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run --install

The output:

```
Created directory fglrx-install.inu6Jw
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver-8.97.100.7.
=====================================================================
AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================
Detected configuration:
Architecture: i686 (32-bit)
X Server: X.Org 6.9 or later
loki_setup: directory: (null)
DKMS part of installation failed.  Please refer to /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for details
```

And the fglrx-install.log:

```
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
Uninstalling any previously installed drivers.

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.97.100.7/source -> /usr/src/fglrx-8.97.100.7

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
cd /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.97.100.7/build; sh make.sh --nohints --uname_r=3.10.25 --norootcheck.....(bad exit status: 1)
[Error] Kernel Module : Failed to build fglrx-8.97.100.7 with DKMS
[Error] Kernel Module : Removing fglrx-8.97.100.7 from DKMS

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 8.97.100.7
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
[Reboot] Kernel Module : update-initramfs
```

After the failure happened, I restarted my laptop to see if it was installed anyway (I ran before aticonfig --initial -f). I opened the ATI Catalyst Control Center and this was what I got:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUIUy.png

Apparently it's installed but strangely I can not activate the compiz effects, the wine does not run games, etc.

Everything was fine with the 2.6.x version of linux but really I want the version > 3.4

Comment: `fglrx` is tied to some particular versions of `Xorg` and of the kernel. Better upgrade (or change) your distribution. Ubuntu 10.10 is quite old.

Comment: just install and use Debian Stable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. 
I kept trying and the error occurs when the command is:
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.25/build SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.970/build/2.6.x modules

Basically the error is because the source code calls create_proc_entry and is deprecated. 
Actually I'm modifying the code to replace create_proc_entry for proc_create. It's the same when I compiled bcwml. I'll let you know if I get it working. To see more error info:
http://pastebin.com/SFCxzZLB

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of specific version dependencies for fglrx, which you probably can't satisfy on your system anymore. I'd recommend upgrading to the next LTS version at least.